# Do you know any tools to remove badware, malware from my website which google blocks?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, security, web

I have a website which google blocked because it had badware i removed the viruses from the server and its completely clean now, the problem that this virus changed in the html, js asp files in the site and added hidden iframes and strange scripts, i removed all what i found in the diles, but the website is toooo big, so any one have any tool which i can use to remove all the effects of this badware?

google gave me this site as a reference to remove the badware from my site
http://www.stopbadware.org/home/security

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upload the latest version of the site from your source control DB. If you dont follow source control, its high time you start doing it. ;-)

Find a good search and replace tool. If you are using Dream weaver then you can do a site wide search. The same is applicable to Visual Interdev as well.

Answer (score 6):

Wipe everything from the server, check all the files, and re upload them if they're clean. Only thing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

+1 William's comment. You can do a simple [grep](http://www.linfo.org/grep.html) for characteristic strings your particular infection has left behind, such as “<iframe” or the start of the encoded scripts, but you can't be sure to find all the changes that have happened without a manual inspection. This is what having a clean copy on your local computer is for.

> i removed the viruses from the server

Really? Are you clean of [rootkits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit)? How can you be sure? After an infection, the only sure-fire way to recover a clean server is to reinstall everything on it from the operating system upwards.

Have you discovered and fixed the method the intruders used to get in? If not, you can be sure another of the Russian malware gangs' automated exploits will be back soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try soswebscan

scan your website at free of cost with soswebscan.

For more details visit soswebscan website : http://soswebscan.jobandproject.com